# Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null while appending to a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I guess it will be a quite obvious answer I'll get but I really can't find it myself.

Here's my table (I spare you all the tds)

```
<table id="COA_Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>some th</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>some TD</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");

    $('#COA_Table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\"></td><td></td>New account<td></td><td></td></tr>');
})
```

and to finish with, the error code I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null

this drives me crazy

Comment: Unable to reproduce: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6QMjC/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that there is an error in your structure

```
<td></td>New account<td></td>
```

This text is not placed anywhere and could be causing the error in your full code.

It should probably be

```
<td></td><td>New account</td>
```

[Demo With These Edits](http://jsfiddle.net/68NGq/)

Comment: ooohhhI had no idea that error could come from the part I'm adding so I did no check... I'll know for the future ! thank you

Answer (score 2):

To avoid issues with invalid markup I would use the following syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr  = $('<tr />'),
        td  = $('<td />'),
        td2 = $('<td />', {text: 'New account'}),
        inp = $('<input />', {type:'checkbox'});

    $('#COA_Table tbody').append( tr.append( td.append(inp), td2 ) );
});
```

which would create each element with opening and closing tags, and append them to the appropriate places.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B4xnf/1/)

Comment: I haven't seen the second argument used before when creating elements like that. That syntax is neat, do you have a link to the documentation for it?

Comment: @adenneo - Also, you should probably not append a `tr` element into a `tr` element.

Comment: @TravisJ - you're right, got confused with the `:last` selector, but just appending the `tr` to the `tbody` would place it last anyway. The documentation for what exactly? Creating elements? If so -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Comment: Yeah, for creating elements. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: indeed it's better to structure. Presently I'm only doing some jquery tests.

Answer (score 0):

append data after the last `tr` and not `tbody` using `after()`

```
 $('#COA_Table tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\"></td><td></td>New account<td></td><td></td></tr>');
```

Comment: actually I've read another thread on this site explaining tbody to be a good solution. anyway wasn't the problem in that case